# Filter nested HTML table using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to filter the following HTML table using jquery.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9mck46m/8/)

Table is a nested html table and I want to filter the column based on key words.
Say keywords are for column 3 its "Paper" and for column 5 its "80". So only row with record Paper and 80 should be displayed.

```
<div id="divQualCodeFuncPMType">
   <table class="SetDWPParameterTabStyle">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="GridHeaderSystemParamter">
         <td>Map Id</td>
         <td>Type Id</td>
         <td>Material Type</td>
         <td></td>
         <td><span id="Label1">Attributes</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><span id="lblMapId">10</span></td>
         <td><span id="Label3">60</span></td>
         <td><span id="Label1">Paper</span></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <span id="Label1">80% cotton</span>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <span id="Label1">20% cotton</span>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><span id="lblMapId">20</span></td>
         <td><span id="Label3">70</span></td>
         <td> <span id="Label1">Box</span></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <span id="Label1">60% cotton</span>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <span id="Label1">40% cotton</span>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><span id="lblMapId">20</span></td>
         <td><span id="Label3">70</span></td>
         <td> <span id="Label1">Wood</span></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <span id="Label1">80% cotton</span>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <span id="Label1">20% cotton</span>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <table>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I have added reference to an earlier post that I am currently using but I does not work any more bcoz of nested table. I tried changing the selector to include the nested table but no success.

Comment: Need to be more specific about what is expected. Question should stand alone and right now is not clear at all. A demo would also help. Why do you not give a class or ID to nested table?

Comment: Dont reference another post, put everything relevant in this post

Comment: now everything is in one place. added jsfiddle as well. Was trying to act lazy ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't both 20% and 80% should be displayed, since the belong in the same outer row? Moreover, you should place the header of the table in `thead` and not in `tbody`. This way you want have to always exclude the first row (because it's the header)